# Multiple Checkboxes with hidden field insert to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a multiple checkboxes  with hidden fields ,   for example

```
<input name="cat" type="hidden" value="1"><input name="features[]" type="checkbox" value="105">

<input name="cat" type="hidden" value="2"><input name="features[]" type="checkbox" value="106">
```

i have a table  like this ,   `features_ID | features_CAT`

how can i insert  checkbox value to `features_ID`  and hiddenfield to `features_CAT`

by the way this is multiple insert.. Thank you for your help..

Answer (score -1):

dunno what hiddens to do with here but to link your features with cats you only need to set the array indexes

```
<input name="features[305][]" type="checkbox" value="105">
<input name="features[215][]" type="checkbox" value="106">
```

then in your PHP you will have `$POST['features']` array which in turn will contain arrays whose keys will be feature ids and values - arrays with cat ids.

just `print_r($_POST);` to make yourself a picture.